# Android studio onmenuitemclicklistener function gives unexpected type specification

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, popup

I'm currently trying to implement a button in my android studio project, using kotlin. I'm not very familiar with kotlin, and so I am referring to this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/popup-menu-in-android-with-example/

I want to create a pop up menu in my android application.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       navigateToMapFragmentIfNeeded(intent)
       // mapbox
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /* Referencing and Initializing the button */
        var popbutton: Button = findViewById<View>(R.id.clickBtn) as Button

        // Setting onClick behavior to the button
        popbutton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { // Initializing the popup menu and 
        //giving the reference as current context
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this@MainActivity, popbutton)

            // Inflating popup menu from popup_menu.xml file
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu())


            // problem line below
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu: OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                fun onMenuItemClick(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    // Toast message on menu item clicked
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "You Clicked " + menuItem.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    return true
                }
            })
            // Showing the popup menu
            popupMenu.show()
        })
        // Request permission
        requestPermission()
    }
```

When I try to run in my emulator, I get these errors for the line I have commented on as "problem line below" in the above code:
"unexpected type specification"
"expecting ,"
"expecting an expression"

Could someone tell me how I could fix this issue?

Any and all help is appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the final `)` in the last line of the setOnMenuItemClickListener:

```
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu: OnMenuItemClickListener(){
        fun onMenuItemClick(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Toast message on menu item clicked
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "You Clicked " + menuItem.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            return true
        }
    }
```